# PDFKit header or footer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to add page numbers to each page of pdf generated using PdfKit. The following is my code :

```
content = File.read( "report.html.erb")
template = ERB.new(content)
set_margin = 0.to_s
kit = PDFKit.new(template.result(binding), :header_center => "Page [page] of [toPage]", page_width: '157.42', page_height: '52.77', :margin_top => set_margin+'in', :margin_right => set_margin+'in', :margin_bottom => set_margin+'in', :margin_left => set_margin+'in')
kit.to_file(file_path)
```

No header is getting displayed on the generated pdf. Please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please type `wkhtmltopdf --help` in console. I believe, you have not patched `Qt` library with `wkhtmltopdf` fixes, hence you will see at the bottom of output:

> Reduced Functionality:
>     This version of wkhtmltopdf has been compiled against a version of QT without
>     the wkhtmltopdf patches. Therefore some features are missing, if you need
>     these features please use the static version.
>
> Currently the list of features only supported with patch QT includes:
>
> - Printing more then one HTML document into a PDF file.
> - Running without an X11 server.
> - Adding a document outline to the PDF file.
> - **Adding headers and footers to the PDF file.**
> - Generating a table of contents.
> - Adding links in the generated PDF file.
> - Printing using the screen media-type.
> - Disabling the smart shrink feature of webkit.

To print out headers and footers one should rebuild `Qt` library with patches provided by `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: What would be an appropriate gem version for above fix?